# Boundary of the image is the image of the boundary.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, change-of-variable, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose that $f:O\to \mathbb R^n$ is a smooth change of variables on the open subset *O* of $\mathbb R^n$. Let D be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $D\cup  \partial D$ is contained in *O*. Show that $f(\partial D)$ = $\partial f(D)$.

My attempt was to try use the Inverse Function Theorem, but I don't know how to start. A smooth change of variable is that $f$ is one to one and its Jacobian is not zero.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What do you mean by "a smooth change of variables"? Does the map $f$ have to be a diffeomorphism? Does it have to be regular (i.e. Jacobian nowhere zero)?

Comment: You mean Jacobian _non-zero_, I guess? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: By the inverse function theorem, $f$ has a differentiable local inverse around every point of its range. Since $f$ is one-to-one, these local inverses paste together to a global inverse $range(f)\to O$, so $f$ is a diffeomorphism, consequently a homeomorphism, and as such, it preserves the topological structures.